# How to get the reason for macOS Catalina regular restart?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, restart

I know, that my remote MacOS restarts daily at the same time (9:30AM).
Energy Saver contains only "Start up or wake" scheduled to 07:45AM.
[image]
I checked the logs for "Previous shutdown cause" by doing
`log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 24h`
and got the answer 
`kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 3`
what means
`Code 3 is a "dirty" Shutdown, which can be caused by any user-initiated Reboot of the computer, or by forcing a hardware computer halt by holding down the power button for 5+ seconds.`
I'm trying to figure out what was the real reason for the restart. What are the possible options here?

Comment: This questions seems better suited for the superuser stackexchange. https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

the reason was a following cronjob:
`30 09 * * * sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now`

find all cron jobs for user:
`crontab -l`